# scala Map with Option/Some gives match error

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, runtime-error

The following code is producing run time error as below. Could reason why the following error. Please explain.

> Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: Some(Some(List(17))) (of class scala.Some)
>       at com.discrete.CountingSupp$.$anonfun$tuplesWithRestrictions1$1(CountingSupp.scala:43)

```
def tuplesWithRestrictions1(): (Int, Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]]) = {
    val df = new DecimalFormat("#")
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0)
    val result = ((0 until 1000) foldLeft[(Int, Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]])] ((0, Map.empty[Int, Option[List[Int]]]))) {
      (r: (Int, Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]]), x: Int) => {
        val str = df.format(x).toCharArray
        if (str.contains('7')) {
          import scala.math._
          val v = floor(log10(x)) - 1
          val v1 = (pow(10, v)).toInt
          val m: Map[Int, Option[List[Int]]] = (r._2).get(v1) match {
            case None => r._2 + (v1 -> Some(List(x)))
            case Some(xs: List[Int]) => r._2 updated(x, Some(x::xs))
          }
          val f = (r._1 + 1, m)
          f
        } else r
      }
    }
    result
  }
```

Comment: Just add `flatten` after the `get()`: `r._2.get(v1).flatten match { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type of `.get` on map is

```
get(k: K): Option[V]
```

## Scala doc

```
  /** Optionally returns the value associated with a key.
   *
   *  @param  key    the key value
   *  @return an option value containing the value associated with `key` in this map,
   *          or `None` if none exists.
   */
  def get(key: K): Option[V]
```

Now,

`r._2.get(v1)` returns an option of Value. So the final return type would be `Option[Option[List[Int]]]`.

You are trying to pattern match for `Option[T]` but the real value type is `Option[Option[Int]]` which is not captured in the match.

1. Use `r._2(v1)` to extract the value and match. Throws exception when `v1` is not found in map.
2. Match inside `map` providing default value.

   ```
   r._2.get(k1).map {
     case None => r._2 + (v1 -> Some(List(x)))
     case Some(value) => r._2 updated(x, Some(x::xs))
   }.getOrElse(defaultValue)
   ```

Comment: I'm little confused I'm assuming that None will get matched when there is no key and itself is default. Then when will get None matched ?

Comment: @Curious In ur case `None` will never get executed

Answer (score 0):

```
def tuplesWithRestrictions1(): (Int, Map[Int, List[Int]]) = {
    val df = new DecimalFormat("#")
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0)
    val result = ((0 until 1000) foldLeft[(Int, Map[Int, List[Int]])] ((0, Map.empty[Int, List[Int]]))) {
      (r: (Int, Map[Int, List[Int]]), x: Int) => {
        val str = df.format(x).toCharArray
        if (str.contains('7')) {
          import scala.math._
          val v = floor(log10(x))
          val v1 = (pow(10, v)).toInt
          val m: Map[Int, List[Int]] = (r._2).get(v1) match {
            case Some(xs: List[Int]) => r._2 updated(v1, x :: xs)
            case None => r._2 + (v1 -> List(x))
          }
          val f = (r._1 + 1, m)
          f
        } else r
      }
    }
    result
  }
```